# Mudar todo tipo de re requisição mantendo os parâmetros e URL via htaccess

Tags: htaccess

Estou quebrando a cabeça a horas tentando entender o tal do htaccess

Minha necessidade é a seguinte, eu tenho um diretório raiz do meu sistema, e cada usuario acessa o sistema pela URL www.meudminio.com.br/nomedousuario

Mas eu preciso que internamente seja carregado www.meudminio.com.br/sistema/index.php, sem revelar ao usuario, e sem trocar a URL, mesmo interagindo com o sistema, se ele tentar acessar:

www.meudminio.com.br/nomeusuario/contas?id=20 seria www.meudminio.com.br/sistema/contas?id=20

O htaccess pode me ajudar nessa?

Comment: O que já tem de htaccess?

Comment: então, eu conheço muito pouco então eu estava fazendo: RewriteRule ^.* www.meudominio.com/sistema [R=302]

Comment: não tem basicamente nada, eu realmente não entendo nada de htaccess, queria saber como faço para fazer redirecionamentos mantendo alguns trechos da URL e os parâmetros sem mudar o endereço pro usuario

Comment: Você já habilitou o rewrite? Senão adicione `RewriteEngine on` no início do `htaccess`. Tente assim `RewriteRule ^(\w*)/contas$ sistema/contas [QSA, L]`, não tenho certeza se irá funcionar..

Comment: estava ativo, ainda não funciona, oque eu tinha até o momento era:
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^meudomonio.com.br/dev[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.meudomonio.com.br/dev/system [r=301,nc]
mas não funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deixe seu `.htaccess` com apenas isto:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Depois programe na `index.php` as rotas que o sistema terá. Veja este artigo: http://rberaldo.com.br/urls-amigaveis-sem-htaccess-usando-slim/

Comment: Na verdade as rotas ja estão configuradas, continua dando erro 500 internal server error

Comment: Veja o log de erros do servidor web. Lá estará o motivo do erro 500

Comment: Desculpa a noobse mas onde eu vejo isso?

Comment: No diretório de instalação do servidor web deve ter um diretório "logs". Se usar Linux, os logs devem estar em /var/logs/apache. Veja mais aqui http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html